# NHibernate/FluentNhibernate session.CreateQuery help

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Hey everyone, im hoping someone can help me. I have a search page in a web app and im trying to construct a custom query to hand to my repository so that when a search is done, only when there are search parameters it will do something. I have the logic done so that it detects when there are parameters, but i still dont know how to construct the query and i cant find a simple enough example through my normal channels online. Can someone offer advice? Or forward me to an online resource? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ayende has a good examples of different queries with nhibernate. 
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/19/nhibernate-queries-examples.aspx